# How to adjust angular mat-table header height ? The table I am working on has column groups(main header and sub headers)

Tags: angular, mat-table, columnheader

I have used sample code from https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html.
But the height property does not seem to work. Is there a way I can customize the height of the main header and subheader?

```
th.mat-header-cell, td.mat-cell {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    padding: 0 !important;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-wnnhyq?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not with the `<td>` elements but with the `<tr>` ones.
just add this:

```
tr.mat-header-row{
   height: 20px !important;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry for my delay in response. This works. Thanks Much !